# Python program subclasses a PyQt5 Window cant setwindow.title in Function

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a sample Python program that sub classes a PyQt5 window.  I am teaching myself and still a little new PyQt5 and python Classes.

The program does what I want to do I ran into an error that I don't understand how to fix. To start this program functions as is, I am currently learning how to run `Threads`.  I imported and sub classed the PyQt5 window.  In the `__init__` section of the subclass I can set the window title and it works fine.

If I move the statement to a function `"def initUI(self):"` I am unable to set the window title, mind you I have tried various versions of the statement and nothing works.  It's the first line of the def and I have it commented out.

My questions are:

1. Is this property setable in a def.
2. If it io what is the proper format of the statement.

---

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Threads import Ui_MainWindow
import sys, time
from time import sleep

class MainWindow_EXEC():
    def __init__(self):             # This section has to be laid out this way 
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(win) 
        self.initUI()               # Inits that need to happen before start up

        win.setWindowTitle("This is the Title!") # Works fine
        win.resize(800,600)
        win.show()  
        sys.exit(app.exec_()) 

    def initUI(self):               # Button assignments
        #self.ui.setWindowTitle("This is the Title!")  # AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'setWindowTitle'
        self.ui.btn_Start.clicked.connect(self.start_progressbar)
        self.ui.btn_Stop.clicked.connect(self.stop_progressbar)
        self.ui.btn_Reset.clicked.connect(self.reset_progressbar)
        self.progress_value = 0
        self.stop_progress = False

    def progressbar_counter(self, start_value=0):
        # have to use member: self.run_thread NOT local var: run_thread
        self.run_thread = RunThread(parent=None, counter_start=start_value)
        self.run_thread.start()
        self.run_thread.counter_value.connect(self.get_thread_value)

    def get_thread_value(self, counter):    #This updates the progress bar
        print(counter)
        if not self.stop_progress:
            self.ui.progressBar.setValue(counter)        

    def start_progressbar(self):    # This is the button that starts the progress bar
        self.stop_progress = False  # This is a switch
        self.progress_value = self.ui.progressBar.value()    # Updating the progress bar    
        self.progressbar_counter(self.progress_value)

    def stop_progressbar(self):     # This is a button to stop the progress bar
        self.stop_progress = True
        self.run_thread.stop()

    def reset_progressbar(self):    # This is a button to reset the progress bar
        self.stop_progressbar()
        self.progress_value = 0
        self.stop_progress = False
        self.ui.progressBar.reset()


class RunThread(QtCore.QThread):

    counter_value = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)                  # define new Signal

    def __init__(self, parent=None, counter_start=0):
        super(RunThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.counter = counter_start
        self.isRunning = True

    def run(self):
        while self.counter < 100 and self.isRunning == True:
            sleep(0.1)
            self.counter += 1
            print(self.counter)
            self.counter_value.emit(self.counter)     # emit new Signal with value

    def stop(self):
        self.isRunning = False
        print('stopping thread...')
        self.terminate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow_EXEC()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objective of the following classes must be distinguished:

- QMainWindow is a widget that has the setWindowTitle method.
- Ui_MainWindow is not a widget but a class that is used to fill a widget so it does not have the setWindowTitle method.

The solution is to make win a class member and then use that object to modify the title:

```
class MainWindow_EXEC():
    def __init__(self):             # This section has to be laid out this way 
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.win) 
        self.initUI() 
        self.win.setWindowTitle("This is the Title!")
        self.win.resize(800,600)
        self.win.show()  
        sys.exit(app.exec_()) 

    def initUI(self):               # Button assignments
        self.win.setWindowTitle("This is the Title!")
        self.ui.btn_Start.clicked.connect(self.start_progressbar)
        # ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  That works as you describe appreciate the answer.